# save and retrieve df as .csv without losing type information

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file-io

When I save a `pandas.DataFrame` to a `.csv` file, a column of `dicts` is converted to literal strings.  How can I save/load a df to `.csv` so that they are equivalent?  I know about pickle, hdf5, etc; I'd like to keep it human readable, but I'm open to alternatives if this is barking up the wrong tree...

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, {3:30}]), ('B', [4, 5, {6:60}])],
 orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t')
df_loaded = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', index_col=0)
df == df_loaded

"""
output:

    one   two  three
A  True  True  False
B  True  True  False
"""
```

Comment: [to_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)?

Comment: @StephenRauch a good suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Try [`pandas.DataFrame.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(
    [('A', [1, 2, {3: 30}]), ('B', [4, 5, {6: 60}])],
    orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

df.to_json('test.csv')
print(pd.read_json('test.csv'))
```

#### Results:

```
   one      three  two
A    1  {'3': 30}    2
B    4  {'6': 60}    5
```